# View Component Not loading properly the css and js is not working on ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi I'm trying to load the viewcomponent using ajax when the button is click. But the view component does work properly it seems that css and js is not working.

Here is the ajax call for the controller Load component

```
$.ajax({
  url: window.location.origin + "/TestDashbook/LoadComponent",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { 'dbid' : dbid },
  complete: function (result) {
        $("#divcontent").empty();
        $("#divcontent").html(result.responseText);
  }
});
```

Here is the Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoadComponent(string dbid)
        {
            var dashtabcount = "0";
            var companyId = "1";
            var defaultdashbooklist = await dashbookService.FetchDefaultDashbooks();
            var dashbooklist = await dashbookService.FetchDashbooks(companyId);
            List<DashbookModelView> dblist = new List<DashbookModelView>();
            DashbookModelView dbmodel = dashbooklist.Where(s => s._id.ToString() == dbid).FirstOrDefault();
            return ViewComponent("TestMultiDash", new { dashbookModel = dbmodel, dashtabcount = dashtabcount, companyId = companyId });
        }
```

**Here is the output**

[image]

**This is what it should look like**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `complete` callback that won't receive the data you are sending back. What you are looking fore is the `success` callback.

From spec:

> **complete**
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "nocontent", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). As of jQuery 1.5, the complete setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> **success**
>   Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>   A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

See the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: hi, I tried changing the complete to success but nothing happen it does not go to fail also.

Comment: Here is the reference that I use. https://damienbod.com/2019/01/24/passing-javascript-values-to-asp-net-core-view-components/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
           success: function (result) {
                  $("#divcontent").empty();
                  $("#divcontent").html(result.responseText);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status + " : operation failed, " + error)
            }
```

Comment: parsererror : operation failed, SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4. What does it mean?

Comment: In this case your code is expecting json response but you are not getting json response.